# How to add new event to fullcalendar.io by clicking on a day

Tags: javascript, node.js, fullcalendar

I have added https://fullcalendar.io into my node project.

[image: Fullcalendar]

And i already displayed some events from our system but i would like to create an event by clicking on a day inside the calendar. Is it possible?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/renderEvent-demo

Comment: @Fox is it the commercial or free version?

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know, this is example in documentation.

Comment: @Fox I'll check it out (even if it's not exactly what i need), thx

Comment: @Gobliins the commercial version just adds a new type of view (the "timeline"). You can still use all the other functions in the free one. But it's worth checking the version number you have used. The demo Fox gave you is for version 3. But the latest version is version 4 and the two are very different. version 3 code will probably not work in v4.

Comment: @Gobliins but abstractly, the best way usually to get users to add events is to handle the "select" callback - selecting allows the user to drag the area of time they want to add the event for (depending on the view being used, this might be a day or days, or it might be a few hours or minutes). The callback then tells you the start and end of the selection. You can then prompt the user to add more details (e.g. a title) and then finally use renderEvent (v3) or addEvent (v4) to place the event on the calendar.